# SSRS page formatting issues

Tags: reporting-services

I have six sub-reports and I would like to arrange them as shown below.
The idea is to show the top one in first page and last two in the second page. When I tried, each report appeared in individual page. Putting first 2 reports ( side by side) in a rectangle and inserting page break after also did not work. 
Each sub reports were generated using matrix.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412272/positioning-tables-and-charts-in-bids-ssrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put the reports inside of a 'Rectangle' object and limit page break scope there.  So if you want the last two only on a new page, put just those two inside a rectangle.  Go into the rectangle's properties and set a page break.

Comment: djangojazz, I did like you said. The problem that I encountered is that when I put two reports side by side than the third one gets pushed to another page. SO I think I am missing something here. Thank you though

Comment: You need to ensure the subreports do not have page breaks set and their alignment in their reports where they are created is similar.  Then you ensure that the rectangle has selected 'keep together on same page if possible.'

Comment: Thank you so much. I double checked my sub reports and guess what ? I had one sub report that did have that page break ( unknowingly made). Now everything works fine. Loved it.