# Layout not same in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I made some reports using SSRS but I have a problem, please see below

[image]

image above is my chart On Design View in Visual studio 2012

But when I upload into CRM and run the report I get this

[image]

Why? When preview on CRM layout not same on first image

but when I export report to PDF layout are same on first image

And how to fix layout are same when preview

Thank you.

Comment: What you are seeing in preview is design view, and in CRM it is generated at run time, it depends on what values you are passing to report.

Comment: I not interest in Value but I interest design of my report  in Visual studio I design like first image but when preview I get design like second image ( I get more space between chart 3 and 4 instead between 2 and 3 )

Comment: I don't understand you, what the difference there in both images other than distinct values for series

Comment: Ok maybe my english is poor. 1st image is in design view in VS2012 (this is correct ) and 2nd image is in reportViewer (this is incorrect) both image are difference is 

in 1st image  : chart1 chart2 .....<space>.... chart3 chart4

in 2nd image : chart1 chart2 chart3 ....<space>.... chart4 

I want report display are same on 1 image

Comment: Ok the problem is with spacing, can you show the code?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412272/positioning-tables-and-charts-in-bids-ssrs/9412668#9412668 would be some help?